# Using String.CharacterView.Index.successor() in for statements

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

In the future, [C-style for statements will be removed from Swift](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0007-remove-c-style-for-loops.md). While there are many alternate methods to using the C-style for statements, such as using `stride`, or the `..<` operator, these only work in some conditions

For example, in older versions of swift, it was possible to loop through every other one of the indexes, [`String.CharacterView.Index`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_String-CharacterView-Index_Structure/index.html), of a String using C-style for statements

```
for var index = string.startIndex; index < string.endIndex; index = string.successor().successor(){
    //code
}
```

Yet this is now deprecated. There is a way to do the same thing, using a `while` loop

```
var index = string.startIndex
while index < string.endIndex{
    //code

    index = index.successor().successor()
}
```

but it isn't much more than a workaround. There is the `..<` operator, which would be perfect for looping through every index of the string

```
for index in string.startIndex..<string.endIndex
```

Yet this doesn't help with looping through every *other* index of the string, or every nth index of the string

Is there any more "swifty" way of looping through every other index of a String other than a `while` loop? This question doesn't just pertain to string indexes, but just objects that have functions such as `.successor()` in general,  where `stride` and `..<` don't work.

Comment: Isn't it `index = index.successor().successor()` in the for loop example ?

Comment: @vadian yes, and that method works now, but it's deprecated and is being removed in a future version of Swift

Comment: Interesting discussion of making a character view strideable here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36205309/conforming-string-characterview-index-to-strideable-fatal-error-when-using-stri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use 'stepping'

```
let str = "abcdefgh"
for i in str.characters.indices where str.startIndex.distanceTo(i) % 2 == 0 {
    print(i,str.characters[i])
}
```

prints

```
0 a
2 c
4 e
6 g
```

UPDATE, based on Sulthan's notes

```
for (i,v) in str.characters.enumerate() where i % 2 == 0 {
    print(i, v)
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is the complexity o `distanceTo`. For integer index `distance` is a simple subtraction, however, for `string` indices `distanceTo` has linear complexity.

Comment: @Sulthan i agree. however, using enumerate has the same trouble

Comment: @Sulthan solution is to create [Character] first

Comment: Nope, enumerate does not need to calculate distance, it is keeping its own index.

Answer (score 4):

Let's do it with functional programming:

```
let text = "abcdefgh"

text.characters
    .enumerate()  // let's get integer index for every character
    .filter { (index, element) in index % 2 == 0 }  // let's filter out every second character
    .forEach { print($0, $1) } // print
```

Result:

```
0 a
2 c
4 e
6 g
```

Comment: Will this suffer for very long strings? I guess `enumerate` is lazy so you should be okay. If not, you could say `characters.lazy`.

Comment: Thanks! This answer was really helpful, but I ended up using [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36194406/2767207) in my code